# Embedding jpg within Liferay Portlet

Tags: image, liferay-6, portlet

I am using Liferay portlets, having an issue embedding jpg images within a view.jsp page.

My directory structure appears as follows:

```
webapp
---myportlet
------view.jsp
------myimage.jpg
```

Within my view.jsp page, I have the following:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myimage.jpg" />
```

The above image path resolves to the following:

```
path = /myportlet/myimage.jpg
```

Within my portlet.xml file, I have the following:

```
<supports>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
</supports>
```

I understand one solution is to put all images within the underlying web/app server and reference that path.  But it is strongly preferred to put these images within the portlet directory.

With that said, some questions:

1. Is it possible to put images within the portlet directory with Liferay
2. Do I need to make further modifications to portlet.xml or liferay-portlet.xml files?
3. Is there a better way to reference image file paths within portlet directories
4. Other ideas?

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question in one post. And there is no _portlet directory_. There is only a directory that contains a JSP file that is used by your portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to embed images within your portlet, and render via the `<img>` tag.  Here's how to do it.

The following code gives you the root directory to where all your images (and other stuff) can be found within the web server:

```
request.getContextPath()
```

You then append to this the following pathname to your image:

```
/html/<yourportletname>/<portletRelativePathToYourImage>
```

In this thread's original post, I stated a portlet named myportlet with an embedded image named myimage.jpg.  So the code to display this image is as follows:

```
<img src='<%=request.getContextPath() + "/html/myportlet/myimage.jpg"%>' />
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: You are describing a way that is not specific to Liferay or portlets, but is a common way for  _all_ webapps.